# Octobercms. How to prepare variable to component template?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Page code:

```
{% partial 'content/main' %}
```

Partial:
[services]

```
{% component 'services' %}
```

Component:

```
public function prepareVars()
    {

        $this->page['servicesList'] = $this->getProperty(); // function returns 123

    }
```

Component template:

```
{{ servicesList }} //does not display anything =(
```

Why is not the variable being passed?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm seems something odd, not sure about your `onRun` method in component

> `prepareVars` will not call automatically we need to call it manually.

did you add `prepareVars` inside `onRun` as when `page life-cycle` called , `onRun` is called automatically so we need to add `prepareVars` there as well, so its code get `executed`.

```
public function onRun()
{
    $this->prepareVars();
}

public function prepareVars()
{
    $this->page['servicesList'] = $this->getProperty(); // function returns 123
}
```

if you are already doing this then please notify it in comment so we can look further.